# Extracting part of string in list to populate a table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have been trying to write a code that read from multiple excel file in folder match a name. I have been able to achieve that part using the code at the show some code. The columns in the dataframe is id and Date.

My issue is I want to add another column called Code that will hold a code extracted from the files list to differentiate each row.

Initial dataframe after reaading the file and combinning that datasets

```
id                          Date              
    ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx  2013-05-09        
    ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx  2013-01-30      
    ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx  2013-02-14        
    ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx  2013-03-19        
    ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx  2013-02-22      
    ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx  2013-02-22
```

The table below shows what i want to achieve:

```
id                          Date            Code   
ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx      2013-05-09      CP1213  
ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx      2013-01-30      CP1213
ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx      2013-02-14      CP1314  
ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx      2013-03-19      CP1314  
ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx      2013-02-22      CP1415 
ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx      2013-02-22      CP1415
```

The output of the files is a list: "ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx" "ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx" "ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx"

```
files <- list.files(path = "ExcelFile/", pattern   = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)



tbl <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

Comment: Do you want to extract `Code` from `files `? `sub("_.*", "", basename(files))` ?

Comment: Yes, so next time when a new file is added to the folder it automatically does that.

Comment: Yes, it will work for all the files with the same pattern. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah I have tried it and it worked but I am thinking of how i can put it beside each row.

Comment: I added an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

Base on  Ronak Shah idea, you can use the **mutate** from the dplyr package then use the **basename** and then extract part of the filename using **sub** from the id.

```
files <- list.files(path = "ExcelFile/", pattern   = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)

tbl <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE) %>% bind_rows(.id = "id")

tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(Code = sub("_.*", "", basename(tbl$id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename` and then extract part of the filename using `sub`

```
df$Code <- sub("_.*", "", basename(as.character(df$id)))

df
#                      id       Date   Code
#1 ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx 2013-05-09 CP1213
#2 ExcelFile/CP1213_.xlsx 2013-01-30 CP1213
#3 ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx 2013-02-14 CP1314
#4 ExcelFile/CP1314_.xlsx 2013-03-19 CP1314
#5 ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx 2013-02-22 CP1415
#6 ExcelFile/CP1415_.xlsx 2013-02-22 CP1415
```

Or if you want to extract it from `files`

```
df$Code <- sub("_.*", "", basename(files))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but, that's not what I want to achieve. I have edited the question again. Sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: @NartRazak I used `df` as dataframe name you have to change it to `tbl`.

Comment: @NartRazak Did it give you any error message or wrong output. I also see that you posted the same answer. How is it different then what I suggested?

Comment: No, but don't worry have been able to make it work using your idea thank you